Continuously read journald with Python
I wrote a monitoring plugin that reads the systemd-journal for a given unit and process it.
My code looks like this:
# Once on start of the monitoring
from systemd import journal
j = journal.Reader()
j.seek_realtime(datetime.now())
j.add_match("_SYSTEMD_UNIT=postfix.service")
j.add_match("_SYSTEMD_UNIT=postfix@-.service")

# Every X Seconds this function is called
def get_metrics():
    for entry in j:
       print(entry)
       # Process the entry

This seems to work first – but after a few hours, the get_metrics function suddenly stops reading new lines. The iterator just returns nothing anymore.
My current guess is that this happens due to rotation or vacuuming of journal files. But how do I detect this and refresh the Reader? I looked at systemd.journal.Reader.process() but didn't get it working.

One way I would do is read the file in while loop, put some time sleep condition or something, and then once task is done, come and read fresh... may be you can use a variable to check contents are same as previous read.

maybe you have to create j = journal.Reader() inside function. OR you can add some code which check how long you use current j and eventually create new j = journal.Reader() every e.g. 1 hour.
